# Json.NET serialize object with root name

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, json, json.net

In my web app I'm using Newtonsoft.Json and I have following object

```
[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonObject(Title = "MyCar")]
public class Car
{
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    public string Name{get;set;}

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName = "owner")]
    public string Owner{get;set;}
}
```

and I want serialize them with root name (class name). This is desired format using

```
{'MyCar':
 {
   'name': 'Ford',
   'owner': 'John Smith'
 }
}
```

I know that I can do that with anonymous object, but is any property or another way in Newtonsoft.Json library?

Answer (score 43):

### Use anonymous class

Shape your model the way you want using anonymous classes:

```
var root = new 
{ 
    car = new 
    { 
        name = "Ford", 
        owner = "Henry"
    }
};

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root);
```

Comment: How can I achieve the same If I am taking object as input in a method that has JsonConvert.SerializeObject. 

`public void SendMessage(object someObject)
{
     JsonConvert.SerializeObject(someObject);
}`

In this case, everytime root element will be "someObject" and not the needed name.

Comment: Where can I find "RootFormatter" class? Which namespace I have to include here?

Comment: @alok_dida seems like it's something very old, I can't find it now - I'll remove this part. Thanks

Answer (score 43):

I found an easy way to render this out... simply declare a dynamic object and assign the first item within the dynamic object to be your collection class...This example assumes you're using Newtonsoft.Json

```
private class YourModelClass
{
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
}

var collection = new List<YourModelClass>();

var collectionWrapper = new {

    myRoot = collection

};

var output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(collectionWrapper);
```

What you should end up with is something like this:

```
{"myRoot":[{"firstName":"John", "lastName": "Citizen"}, {...}]}
```

Comment: if we return string ... in result show extra quotations...  that should be removed .... by this link http://forums.asp.net/t/1821728.aspx?Web+API+project+returning+JSON+issues

Comment: This works. I was looking for something like this to avoid having to declare a wrapper `RootObject` class.

Comment: What is `myRoot`?

Comment: @Delfino `myRoot` is just an abitrary string, you can specify anything you want there.

Comment: This worked to give me a list that was compatible with JsonConfig, to read into a collection from a JsonConfig config file (settings.conf) after a small amount of find-and-replace editing. I could RegEx it to this form if I needed the whole thing repeatedly automated. This was what I was after in the JsonConfig settings file: TestsToRun:["MySpecFlowXunitTest1.dll","MySpecFlowXunitTestOther.dll","MySpecFlowXunitTestYetAnother.dll"]   and then this C# line reads them using JsonConfig: List<string> allowedTestsList = Config.Global.TestsToRun;

Answer (score 13):

You can easily create your own serializer

```
var car = new Car() { Name = "Ford", Owner = "John Smith" };
string json = Serialize(car);
```

---

```
string Serialize<T>(T o)
{
    var attr = o.GetType().GetCustomAttribute(typeof(JsonObjectAttribute)) as JsonObjectAttribute;

    var jv = JValue.FromObject(o);

    return new JObject(new JProperty(attr.Title, jv)).ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Sorry, my english is not that good. But i like to improve the upvoted answers.
I think that using Dictionary is more simple and clean.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            agencia ag1 = new agencia()
            {
                name = "Iquique",
                data = new object[] { new object[] {"Lucas", 20 }, new object[] {"Fernando", 15 } }
            };
            agencia ag2 = new agencia()
            {
                name = "Valparaiso",
                data = new object[] { new object[] { "Rems", 20 }, new object[] { "Perex", 15 } }
            };
            agencia agn = new agencia()
            {
                name = "Santiago",
                data = new object[] { new object[] { "Jhon", 20 }, new object[] { "Karma", 15 } }
            };


            Dictionary<string, agencia> dic = new Dictionary<string, agencia>
            {
                { "Iquique", ag1 },
                { "Valparaiso", ag2 },
                { "Santiago", agn }
            };

            string da = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dic);

            Console.WriteLine(da);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }


    }

    public class agencia
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public object[] data { get; set; }
    }
```

This code generate the following json (This is desired format)

```
{  
   "Iquique":{  
      "name":"Iquique",
      "data":[  
         [  
            "Lucas",
            20
         ],
         [  
            "Fernando",
            15
         ]
      ]
   },
   "Valparaiso":{  
      "name":"Valparaiso",
      "data":[  
         [  
            "Rems",
            20
         ],
         [  
            "Perex",
            15
         ]
      ]
   },
   "Santiago":{  
      "name":"Santiago",
      "data":[  
         [  
            "Jhon",
            20
         ],
         [  
            "Karma",
            15
         ]
      ]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
string Json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Car { Name = "Ford", Owner = "John Smith" }, Formatting.None);
```

for the root element use GlobalConfiguration.

Answer (score 4):

A very simple approach for me is just to create 2 classes.

```
public class ClassB
{
    public string id{ get; set; }
    public string name{ get; set; }
    public int status { get; set; }
    public DateTime? updated_at { get; set; }
}

public class ClassAList
{
    public IList<ClassB> root_name{ get; set; } 
}
```

And when you going to do serialization:

```
var classAList = new ClassAList();
//...
//assign some value
//...
var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(classAList)
```

Lastly, you will see your desired result as the following:

```
{
  "root_name": [
    {
      "id": "1001",
      "name": "1000001",
      "status": 1010,
      "updated_at": "2016-09-28 16:10:48"
    },
    {
      "id": "1002",
      "name": "1000002",
      "status": 1050,
      "updated_at": "2016-09-28 16:55:55"
    }
  ]
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can at least tell Json.NET to include the type name: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_TypeNameHandling.htm . `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer jser = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer();
jser.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects;`

The type will be included at the beginning in the "$type" property of the object.

This is not exactly what you are looking for, but it was good enough for me when facing a similiar problem.

Answer (score 2):

Writing a custom [JsonConverter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) is another approach mentioned in similar questions. However, due to nature of how `JsonConverter` is designed, using that approach for this question is tricky, as you need to be careful with the `WriteJson` implementation to avoid getting into infinite recursion: [JSON.Net throws StackOverflowException when using [JsonConvert()]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29719509/json-net-throws-stackoverflowexception-when-using-jsonconvert/38314018).

One possible implementation:

```
public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    //JToken t = JToken.FromObject(value); // do not use this! leads to stack overflow
    JsonObjectContract contract = (JsonObjectContract)serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(value.GetType());

    writer.WriteStartObject();
    writer.WritePropertyName(value.GetType().Name);
    writer.WriteStartObject();
    foreach (var property in contract.Properties)
    {
        // this removes any property with null value
        var propertyValue = property.ValueProvider.GetValue(value);
        if (propertyValue == null) continue;

        writer.WritePropertyName(property.PropertyName);
        serializer.Serialize(writer, propertyValue);
        //writer.WriteValue(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(property.ValueProvider.GetValue(value))); // this adds escaped quotes
    }
    writer.WriteEndObject();
    writer.WriteEndObject();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this help.

```
//Sample of Data Contract:

[DataContract(Name="customer")]
internal class Customer {
  [DataMember(Name="email")] internal string Email { get; set; }
  [DataMember(Name="name")] internal string Name { get; set; }
}

//This is an extension method useful for your case:

public static string JsonSerialize<T>(this T o)
{
  MemoryStream jsonStream = new MemoryStream();
  var serializer = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
  serializer.WriteObject(jsonStream, o);

  var jsonString = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(jsonStream.ToArray());

  var props = o.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(false);
  var rootName = string.Empty;
  foreach (var prop in props)
  {
    if (!(prop is DataContractAttribute)) continue;
    rootName = ((DataContractAttribute)prop).Name;
    break;
  }
  jsonStream.Close();
  jsonStream.Dispose();

  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(rootName)) jsonString = string.Format("{{ \"{0}\": {1} }}", rootName, jsonString);
  return jsonString;
}

//Sample of usage

var customer = new customer { 
Name="John",
Email="john@domain.com"
};
var serializedObject = customer.JsonSerialize();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary too and even better add a method to the class itself:

```
public class Car
{
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    public string Name{get;set;}

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName = "owner")]
    public string Owner{get;set;}

    public string ToJson(string rootName)
    {            
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, Car>
        {
            { rootName, this }
        };

        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dictionary);
    }
}

// Use:
var car = new Car()
{ 
    Name = "Ford", 
    Owner = "Henry"
};

car.ToJson("myCar");
```

Answer (score -5):

```
[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonObject(Title = "root")]
public class TestMain
```

this is the only attrib you need to add to get your code working.