# WebAPI JSON Class name missing

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I have a response wrapper class that has a list of items (classA) that i need to return, however the JSON when I look in fiddler is not showing the type of items in the list it is simple showing {}.

then following is the JSON representation as show in fiddler:

```
-JSON
   - Data
       - {}
            - Prop1=value1
       - {}
            - Prop1=value2
```

What i need is the following:

```
-JSON
   - Data
       - classA
            - Prop1=value1
       - classA
            - Prop1=value2
```

can anyone tell me how to achieve this?

NOTES:

1. C# WebAPI being used
2. Response type is HttpReqponseMessage
3. Creation of response is

   HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, responseModel);

Answer (score 1):

I think Web API is now using JSON.NET for the serialization.

So, check this answer on JSON .NET...

[Json.NET serialize object with root name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16294963/json-net-serialize-object-with-root-name)