# How can I serialize an object as Json adding as root the name of the object class in a desktop C# app?

Tags: c#, .net, json

Supposing I have this object:

```
 var user = new User() { name = "John" };
```

When I am trying to send this object as Json to an web server using this code:

```
 HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, user);
```

this is the json that is sent:

```
{name:"John"}
```

I would want to insert a root node. The Json should look like this:

```
{user:{name:"John"}
```

I found a solution, but it was only for web apps. Any ideas for desktop apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an anonymous object to wrap up your user object e.g.

```
var userObj = new User() { name = "John" };
client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, new { user = userObj });
```

Comment: James it seams that your method is working. But still is not the best because every time I call the method I have to specify the name of the root which is a disadvantage that will affect my work. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: @RazvanFlorea Well you could create a wrapper class if you'd prefer but I'd say you aren't really gaining much. Why would this code present such a big issue?

Comment: For example if I want to make a method that takes as arguments the object to be sent and the url (method that will be called for sending different objects), then, probably, I have to come with one more argument which will be the name of the root, which does not seem to be very elegant. I was thinking about a solution that is taking advantage of the object that is sent. Here you can see a solution for ASP.NET apps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16294963/json-net-serialize-object-with-root-name