# JSON C# .NET Compile Class Name

Tags: c#, jquery, json

I am working on a C# project however I am in need of some advice.

I am presently posting to my site:

```
{Tags : 'App', Limit : '10' }
```

And it can cast this to the following class

```
[Serializable]
public class MiloFilter
{
    public string Tags { get; set; }
    public string Limit { get; set; }
}
```

However what I am wanting to accomplish is that I would like to post my JSON like this:

```
{ MiloFilter : {Tags : 'SomeTag', Limit : '1' }}
```

However when I try and parse it using the following method it fails.

```
var js = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
var miloFilter = js.Deserialize<MiloFilter>(bodyText);
```

How can I acomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily create your own serializer

```
var car = new Car() { Name = "Ford", Owner = "John Smith" };
string json = Serialize(car);
```

---

```
string Serialize<T>(T o)
{
    var attr = o.GetType().GetCustomAttribute(typeof(JsonObjectAttribute)) as JsonObjectAttribute;

    var jv = JValue.FromObject(o);

    return new JObject(new JProperty(attr.Title, jv)).ToString();
}
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16295435/191220)

Comment: OP is using [`JavaScriptSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) not [`Json.NET`](http://james.newtonking.com/json).