# Add Object from razor to js list not working

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-5

i get this in chrome debug  `picsList.push(BL.datafuncs+pics);`
a string
insted of `picsList.push([{img:"",url:""}]);` an object

```
<script>
 var picsList = [];

    @foreach (var item in BL.datafuncs.GetMainPagePics())
        {
             @:picsList.push(@item);
        }
</script>


 public class pics
        {
            public string img { get; set; }
            public string url { get; set; }
        }

        public static List<pics> GetMainPagePics()
        {
            List<pics> a = new List<pics>();

                    pics p =new pics();
                    p.img = "", 
                    p.url = "";
                    a.Add(p);

            return a;
        }
```

Comment: I think razor is using "ToString()" method of "item". Maybe [JsonConvert.SerializeObject](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16953002/1440095)?

Comment: Please, mark as anwser if help ya! tks! =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert object to json, you can try:

```
@:picsList.push(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(item)));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think razor is using "ToString()" method of "item". 
Maybe [JsonConvert.SerializeObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16294963/json-net-serialize-object-with-root-name/16953002#16953002)?

;P