# Trouble serializing c# to json

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I'm trying to serialize a c# object to json to post to an external rest api.

The description to on property in my object was "LineItems is a list of LineItem"

So based on that, in C# i'd simply do this:

```
public List<LineItem> lineItems { get; set; }

public class LineItem
{
    public string dealerProductCode { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string quantity { get; set; }
    public string amount { get; set; }
}
```

Which would serialize into json like so:

```
{
        //other properties etc

       "lineItems":[
          {
             "dealerProductCode":"asdf",
             "description":"asdf",
             "quantity":"1",
             "amount":"100"
          }
       ]
    }
```

However, they give two examples, one in xml and one in json.

json:

```
{
    //other properties etc

   "lineItems":{
      "lineItem":[
         {
            "dealerProductCode":"asdf",
            "description":"asdf",
            "quantity":"1",
            "amount":"100"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

To me, this looks like...
 - An object called lineItems
 - That contains an array called lineItem
 - The first item in that array is a lineItem object

In the xml example it seems to make a lot more sense:

```
<lineItems>
    <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
    <lineItem>
        <dealerProductCode>asdf</dealerProductCode>
        <description>asdf</description>
        <quantity>1</quantity>
        <amount>1</amount>
    </lineItem>
</lineItems>
```

How can I craft my C# to produce the json output they have in their example?

Comment: Side comment, you are right. Their JSON example is counter-intuitive.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do the example you want, but for me it makes sense the way they are doing it: First, you get the variable name (`lineItems`) and then, before the array, you need a way to send the type of the items (`lineItem`). Maybe it looks confusing, but it's functional

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/16295052/1841212

Comment: Here is a nice tool for going from Json to c#. It may require a few tweaks but it works as a good starting point. http://json2csharp.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you'll serialize an instance of Data class, you'll obtain the json from the example.

```
public class LineItem
{
    public string dealerProductCode { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string quantity { get; set; }
    public string amount { get; set; }
}

public class LineItemContainer
{
 public List<LineItem> lineItem{get;set;}
}

public class Data
{
  public LineItemContainer lineItems {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have ran into a similar problem before.

So, using the answer [here](http://solvedstack.com/questions/custom-conversion-of-specific-objects-in-json-net), and [JSON.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) serializer,

This can be achieved by defining custom JsonConverter and overriding the name.

It will work for all IEnumerable objects.

First decorate the IEnumerable object with the following annotation:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(JSONSettings.AssociativeArraysConverter<LineItemFieldNameResolver>))] 
public List<LineItem> lineItems { get; set; }
```

Here is the custom implementation,

```
   public class LineItemFieldNameResolver : IAssociateFieldNameResolver
        {
            public string ResolveFieldName(object i_Object)
            {
                var item = (i_Object as LineItem);
                return "lineitem";
            }
        }

        public class AssociativeArraysConverter<T> : JsonConverter
            where T : IAssociateFieldNameResolver, new()
        {
            private readonly T _mFieldNameResolver;

            public AssociativeArraysConverter()
            {
                _mFieldNameResolver = new T();
            }

            public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue,
                JsonSerializer serializer)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException(
                    "Unnecessary because CanRead is false. The type will skip the converter.");
            }

            public override bool CanRead
            {
                get { return false; }
            }

            public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
            {
                return typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(objectType) &&
                       !typeof(string).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
            }

            public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
            {
                var collectionObj = value as IEnumerable;

                writer.WriteStartObject();

                foreach (var currObj in collectionObj)
                {
                    writer.WritePropertyName(_mFieldNameResolver.ResolveFieldName(currObj));
                    serializer.Serialize(writer, currObj);
                }

                writer.WriteEndObject();
            }
        }

        public interface IAssociateFieldNameResolver
        {
            string ResolveFieldName(object i_Object);
        }
```

I hope this helps. :)