# How to add a root node to a JSON in C# using Json.NET?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am working on `Visual Studio` `C#` project and I need to convert a `JSON` to `XML`. 
I receive the `JSON` in string format.
The problem is, I need to have a root node in the `JSON` structure if the `JSON` doesn't have one, so that I can convert to `XML` with desired format.

Supose I have this `JSON`:

```
{
        "id": 1,
        "name": {
            "first": "Yong",
            "last": "Mook Kim"
        },
        "contact": [{
            "type": "phone/home",
            "ref": "111-111-1234"
        }, {
            "type": "phone/work",
            "ref": "222-222-2222"
        }]
}
```

And I want to add root node to that `JSON` just like that:

```
{
    "user": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": {
            "first": "Yong",
            "last": "Mook Kim"
        },
        "contact": [{
            "type": "phone/home",
            "ref": "111-111-1234"
        }, {
            "type": "phone/work",
            "ref": "222-222-2222"
        }]
    }
}
```

How can I do it with `C#` and `JSON.NET`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Json.NET serialize object with root name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16294963/json-net-serialize-object-with-root-name)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suppose you have `user` object. Just use anonymous class to add extra root node:

```
var obj = new { user = user };

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
```

The resulting JSON will look like that:

```
{
    "user": {.../your user object/...}
}
```