# Serialize object with class name as root element

Tags: c#, json, restsharp

I am using RestSharp and would like to JSON serialize the request with the DTO's class name as root element. Here's an example DTO class:

```
public class NewToken {
    public string user_name { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public string audience { get; set; }
}
```

I would like the request generated to be:

```
{ "NewToken" : { "user_name": "asdf", "password": "asdfasdf", "audience": "test" }}
```

I realise I can use anonymous class such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16294963/json-net-serialize-object-with-root-name), but is there a way I can do this automatically using the class name as root element?

Here are some more code snippets for the API client:

```
public abstract class ApiBase
    {
        internal string _defaultServer = Properties.Settings.Default.DefaultServer;
        internal int _defaultPort = Properties.Settings.Default.DefaultPort;

        public T Execute<T>(RestRequest request) where T : new()
        {
            var client = new RestClient();
            client.AddHandler("application/json", new CustomJsonSerialiser());
            client.BaseUrl = new Uri($"https://{this._defaultServer}:{this._defaultPort}");
            client.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

            var response = client.Execute<T>(request);
            return response.Data;
        }

        internal RestRequest CreateBasicRequest()
        {
            var request = new RestRequest();
            request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
            request.JsonSerializer = new CustomJsonSerialiser();
            request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json, application/binary");
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            return request;
        }

        internal RestRequest CreateAuthenticatedRequest(string tokenId)
        {
            var request = this.CreateBasicRequest();
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", $"Bearer {tokenId}");
            return request;
        }
    }

public class SessionManager : ApiBase
    {

        public SessionManager() { }

        public SessionManager(string server, int port)
        {
            this._defaultServer = server;
            this._defaultPort = port;
        }

        public Token GetToken()
        {
            var request = this.CreateBasicRequest();
            request.Method = Method.POST;
            request.Resource = "token";
            request.AddBody(new { NewToken = new NewToken() { user_name = "dotnet", password = "dotnetdotnet", audience = "api" } });
            var token = Execute<Token>(request);
            return token;
        }

        public Token RenewToken(Token token)
        {
            var request = this.CreateAuthenticatedRequest(token.id);
            request.Method = Method.POST;
            request.Resource = "token-renew";
            var new_token = Execute<Token>(request);
            return new_token;
        }
    }
```

In `SessionManager.GetToken()` I am creating an anonymous object to get it serialised correctly. I'm after an automated way, something integrated into the serialisation process, that will wrap the object in a root element with the same name as the DTO class.

Comment: from looking at the link you've supplied, Json.Net can add the objects type. you could use that i guess ?

Comment: What happens if a property in `NewToken` were a custom type? `public Person User { get; set; }`. How would that be serialized?

Answer (score 0):

When you create request, use `request.RootElement = "NewToken";`

Comment: Pretty sure I tried that and it didn't add a root element.

Comment: @codedog Can you provide more code about calling rest service?

Comment: I have added more code snippets, I hope that's enough?