# Include Class name as part of the serialization in JSON C#

Tags: c#, json, reflection, json.net

I have a specific situation where I need to include the class name as property in JSON when classes are serialized. The tricky parts is I need to do this dynamically. I can't just create an anonymous class before calling serialization.

I have decorated my class with a custom attribute as below:

```
 [OntologyArea("con", " http://someurl/area/DomicileAddress")]
    public class DomicileAddress : IContactPoint
    {

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "con:hasAddressPoint")]
        public IAddressPoint AddressPoint
        {
            get; set;
        }
    }
```

In the above example the `OntologyArea` attribute should be read and included as a Property. The propery name should be the first argument of `OntologyArea` + the class name (i.e con:DomicileAddress) and the value should be the concrete class of `IAddressPoint`.

The tricky part is that the concrete class of IAddressPoint might need to do the same as shown here:

```
[OntologyArea("geo", "http://someurl.net/geolocation")]
    public class StreetAddress : IAddressPoint
    {
        [JsonProperty("geo:hasStartingStreetNumber")]
        public string StartingStreetNumber
        {
            get; set;
        }
    }
```

an example of JSON:

```
"con:DomicileAddress" : {
    "con:hasAddressPoint" : {
        "geo:StreetAddress" : {
            "geo:hasEndingStreetNumber" : ""
        }
    }
}
```

So if any object does have a `OntologyArea` attribute I need to add a parent level. If it does not contain this attribute normal serilization should continue.

Please let me know If I need to explain more.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Json.NET serialize object with root name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16294963/json-net-serialize-object-with-root-name)

Comment: I can't use a dynamic object as this must done on runtime. But thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this solution for specifying the concrete type is a must or is it just your proposed solution?

Because Json.NET has a built-in support for encoding the actual types for properties of interface types or base classes:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myContract, new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto });
```

If you really need a completely custom logic you have to implement a converter, which also can be passed to the `JsonSerializerSettings`. It must be derived from `JsonConverter` and you have to implement the `WriteJson` method to emit your desired json sting using low level tokens just like in case of an `XmlWriter`:

```
private class MyConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(IAddressPoint).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var address = (IAddressPoint)value;

        writer.WriteStartObject(); // {
        writer.WritePropertyName($"geo:{address.GetType().Name}"); // "geo:StreetAddress"
        // ... etc.
        writer.WriteEndObject(); // }

        // or you can just emit raw string:
        writer.WriteRaw(myJsonBody);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, 
    {
        // todo: and the deserialization part goes here
    }
}
```

Comment: I must support concrete types. Where do I put this JsonConverter attribute? On the Interface of IAddressPoint? And If I have another Interface I will create a custom converter for that interface as well? Thanks.

Comment: You can put that above the property but it is not needed. You can pass a collection of converters to the serializer settings and then `CanConvert` will be called for each property. By returning `true` for multiple types you can use a single converter for all of the custom types. But then in `WriteJson` the `value` can have any of these types and you must handle all of them.

Comment: Is it possible for you to make a more detailed example? That will be very great..

Answer (score 0):

This pointed me in the correct direction. I have an attribute that is read in this class and appended to the writer object.