# Add root name to Json string

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

I have a code that generate Json string .

```
public class Work
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public bool status { get; set; }
    public bool open { get; set; }
   
}
public class Root
{
    public IList<Work> work { get; set; }    
}


public void Work_add(string id, string nameM)
    {                    
        _work.Add(new Work()
        {
            id = id,
            name = nameM,
            status = false,
            open = false
        });
    }
    
public List<Work> _work = new List<Work>(); 

public void Print_Json()
{
.
.
string jsonE = JsonConvert.SerializeObject( _work);
}
```

When a list is populated and then serialised I get this JSON:

```json
[{"id":"1","name":"AAA","status":"false","open":"false"},{"id":"2","name":"BBB","status":"false","open":"false"},{"id":"4","name":"CCC","status":"false","open":"false"},{"id":"5","name":"DDD","status":"false","open":"false"},{"id":"6","name":"EEE","status":"false","open":"false"},{"id":"7","name":"FFF","status":"false","open":"false"},{"id":"8","name":"GGG","status":"false","open":"false"}]
```

I looked in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16294963/json-net-serialize-object-with-root-name) and in other solutions, but I'm missing somethings....

I need add `"work"` name before the list with `{`,`}`

```json
{"work":[{"id":"1","name":"AAA","status":"false","open":"false"},{"id":"2","name":"BBB","status":"false","open":"false"},{"id":"4","name":"CCC","status":"false","open":"false"},{"id":"5","name":"DDD","status":"false","open":"false"},{"id":"6","name":"EEE","status":"false","open":"false"},{"id":"7","name":"FFF","status":"false","open":"false"},{"id":"8","name":"GGG","status":"false","open":"false"}]}
```

Comment: Is `Print_Json` a member of the `Root` class? If yes, do `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);` instead

Comment: No, It's independent functions

Comment: So were does `work` come from in that method? Please provide reproducible code

Comment: That is a problem, I don't have enough IQ how to implement it. I understand that I need link _work with the Root class and call it in JsonConvert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do the following.

```
public void Print_Json()
{
  var root = new Root();
  root.work = _work;
  string jsonE = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root);
}
```

Comment: A thousand Thanks!!!! Works!